# How to find Unix system() function path in C

Tags: c, unix

i am doing a project about shell, and i want the code that gives me the path the system() function uses.

example, when i enter the command

type dir

the reply will be

dir is external command (/bin/dir)

this is what i reached, but its not working

```
else if(strcmp(arg3[0],"type")==0) //if type command
        {
            if(strcmp(arg3[1],"cat")==0 || strcmp(arg3[1],"rm")==0 || strcmp(arg3[1],"rmdir")==0 || strcmp(arg3[1],"ls")==0 || strcmp(arg3[1],"cp")==0 ||                   strcmp(arg3[1],"mv")==0 || strcmp(arg3[1],"exit")==0 || strcmp(arg3[1],"sleep")==0 || strcmp(arg3[1],"type")==0|| strcmp(arg3[1],"history") ==0)
            {
                printf("%s is a Rshell builtin\n", arg3[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%s is an external command\n", arg3[1]); 
                char * pPath;
                pPath = getenv ("PATH");
                 if (pPath!=NULL)
                    printf ("The current path is: %s",pPath);


            }
        }
```

Comment: You shouldn't call those system calls, because a system call is something entirely different.

Comment: Please be more specific with "not working"?  Are you getting an error message? What is it? What output do you see, and how does it differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for the `which` command:

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
```

Comment: how to implemented in C

is it just like this $ which(arg[1])

where arg[1] contains the command name
??

Comment: how to use the which in the coding??

Comment: @charly: To do the same thing as the `which` command, use `getenv("PATH")`, separate the individual elements with `:`, and look for the desired command in each path element.

Comment: @charly: Your code above is incomplete, it doesn't split the path apart on the `:` character.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [which](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which)?

```
which <command>
```

will show you where the executable is located

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how the searching functionality of the  "type" command works, it simply searches all the directories contained in the PATH environment variable until it finds the specified file (which must be executable by the user). This is quite easy to implement yourself - I don't think there is a POSIX library  function that does it, but I'm no POSIX expert.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

First off note that system() will use another shell, not yours.  Most implementations use  the default of /bin/sh, which could be a Bourne shell or bash... you need to find out what your c runtime does.  popen() almost always does the same as system()  anyway this is true
on Solaris, HPUX, and with glibc.

```
FILE *cmd=popen("/usr/bin/echo $PATH");
char tmp[256]={0x0};

if (cmd!=NULL)
{
   while (fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp), cmd)!=NULL)   
     printf("%s", tmp);
   pclose(cmd);
}

/* or */
system("/usr/bin/echo $PATH");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always try downloading the open source code for `whereis` which is standard on most Linux distributions and read up the code and see how it is implemented.